# React Import Multiple Functions

Tags: reactjs

```
import {test,test1,test3} from 'react'
```

Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
import {test,test1,test3} as R from 'react'

So in my code it will be:

R.test();
R.test1();
R.test3();
```

Comment: How about `import * as R from 'react'`?

Comment: boom!!! your the man

Answer (score 8):

```
import * as R from 'somecomponent';
```

This imports all functions and components which are marked as `export` in `somecomponent` and make a group of them as `R`.

```
R.test();
R.test1();
R.test2();
```

Or

```
import { test, test1, test2 } from 'somecomponent';
```

This imports these functions from `somecomponent`. They should be exported like this.

```
export const test = () => {};
export const test1 = () => {};
export const test2 = () => {};
```

Then you can call them like below:

```
test();
test1();
test2();
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, here are some functions in `utils/DateUtils.js`

```
export function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}

export function addMonths(date, months) {
    var result = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months));
    return result;
}
```

Here is how I declare the functions in my component:

```
import * as DateUtils from '../utils/DateUtils';
```

I can then use every DateUtils's exported functions in my view's component:

```
<h3>Expiry: {DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), 2 * 7).toLocaleDateString() (in 2 weeks)</h3>
<h3>Expiry: {DateUtils.addMonths(new Date(), 2).toLocaleDateString()} (in 2 months)</h3>
```